# How to avoid writing multiple && operators in if statement?

Tags: javascript

I have a if statement where I have multiple && operators.

```
if (firstname.value !=="" && lastname.value !=="" && phone.value !=="" && emailverified.value ==="1" && personcheck.checked === false){
//something//
}else{
//something else//
}
```

How can I put these into a single line and insert it in if statement so I can avoid multiple operators? Like this?

````
if (condition){
//something//
} else{
//something else//
}```
````

Comment: Use the `required` attribute instead, to start with - move it out of the JS

Comment: @CertainPerformance well, based on the OP's approach it doesn't look like the form is directly submitted, rather that it is being preprocessed by JS. The OP would then have to end up doing lots of `.checkValidity()`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

create one more function called `isValid`

```
function isValid() {
return firstname.value !=="" && lastname.value !=="" && phone.value !=="" && emailverified.value ==="1" && personcheck.checked === false;
}
```

````
if (isValid()){
//something//
} else{
//something else//
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can group the ones comparing similar things to one group and shorten the other ones, something like:

```js
if ([firstname, lastname, phone].every(({ value }) => value.length)
    && emailverified.value == 1 && !personcheck.checked) {
  // ...
} else {
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

````js
const condition = firstname.value !=="" && lastname.value !=="" && phone.value !=="" && emailverified.value ==="1" && personcheck.checked === false

if (condition){
//something//
} else{
//something else//
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps give nested "if" statements a try.

Comment: Yep, someone would definitely prefer `if(firstname.value !== "") { if(lastname.value !== "") { if(phone.value !== "") { if(emailverfied.value === "1") { if(personcheck.checked === false) { 
/* do whatever you're doing */ } else { /* do something */ } } else { /* do the same thing */ } } else { /* do the same thing */ } } else { /* do the same thing */ } } else { /* do the same thing */ }`.